# Edit to comment has pink/red background and not showing

Tags: support

[My first answer to a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/319477/catchall-ssl-needs-to-be-applied-on-amazon-server-with-elastic-ip) on Serverfault got changed to a comment. I fully understand why this was so. While pointing to what I believed to be the problem it didn't actually 'answer' the question.

Once I realised my error I edited the comment to explain my point more fully and so be more helpful. However when I look at the question withut being logged in I only see my comment (and one other answer by a different user).

When logged in I see my edited comment in the answers section but it has pink/red background.

I assume this means it needs to be approved or something but I can't find anything in the site FAQs to explain this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That color background means that your answer was deleted and no normal users can see them. 10k reputation users can see all deleted answers, as can moderators. You can always see your own deleted content, but normal users will not see this.

The reason that they show up like that is that high rep users can vote to undelete content if they feel that it is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark stated this is because it was deleted (which happens automatically when your post gets converted to a comment). I have undeleted the answer, as it is now much more of a useful answer.